# Requested scopes not included in access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

I want a custom scope called `avm.read` to be inclued in the scopes of the access token when requesting it.

I have an ApiResource called `compApi` and an ApiResourceScope called `avm.read`.
I've also added an ApiScope `avm.read` and added the `avm.read` to the ClientScopes.

When requesting the token, I'm also requesting the following scopes:

- openid
- profile
- email
- **avm.read**

After retrieving the token and deserializing it with jwt.io, I only see the openid in the scopes array:

```
"scope": [
    "openid"
  ],
```

What do I have to do in addition to what I already did so that the `avm.read` custom scope is also included in the scope array of the token?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post some sample code?

Comment: Whant OAuh2 flow do you use (auth code, client credentials)?

Comment: Have you, as a user actually given consent for the API scopes? If not, you would not see them in the token.  Only the consented scopes is included.

Comment: I'm using the auth code flow and yes, the user has given consent to the scope

Comment: Did you add that scope "avm.read" in AllowedScope for your client registration ?